# htaccess prevent page extensions displaying

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have my htaccess file set up so that my website pages don't need to display an extension, my links are setup like this, with the slash at the end:

```
 www.mywebsite/about/
```

These links work - But if I were to directly type in

```
 www.mywebsite/about.html
```

The website will show this page with the html extension. Is there a way that I can prevent extensions from showing even if they are directly typed in? :S

The majority of my pages are html, except for one php page. This is what I have in my htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^php-page/([^/\.]+)/?$ php-page.php?p=$1 [L]
```

If anyone can help me out with this I would really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Why bother? If you don't ever create any links to the ".html" version of the URL, no-one will ever know it's there and it will never receive any traffic. I think you're just making life hard for yourself trying to do this. Unnecessary complexity leads to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.html$
RewriteRule .* %1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]

RewriteRule ^php-page/([^/\.]+)/?$ php-page.php?p=$1 [L]
```

I think it can be done a bit better than this, but it should work.